# Multiple TabHost. Implementing TabHost alike container inside Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost

Since we cannot nest fragments (Android < 4.2) I wonder what is the best way to create views structure like this:

- at the bottom: main tabs bar (similar to iOS one)
- in the middle: content of current tab

  - one of the tab contains tabs bar (displayed on the top of the screen)
- on the top: independent text view

I was thinking about TabActivity inside each of the bottom tabs but it is currently deprecated and Fragment shoud be used instead. On the other hand, if I will use a Fragment to implement a bottom tab I cannot nest another fragment (FragmentTabHost) to implement second tab bar below the view on the top (independent text view).
Frankly speaking, the best option for me would be to have each of the main tab (in bottom tab bar) as independent Activity / FragmentActiviy.

Is there a fairly easy way to do this?

Comment: Nested fragments are supported all the way back to Android 1.6 via the Support Library.

Comment: "Since we cannot nest fragments (Android < 4.2)" -- yes, you can, by  using the Android Support package's backport of fragments. "at the bottom: main tabs bar" -- do not use bottom tab bars: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html